# c# efficient way to add an escape for some characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

i need to replace some charachters in a string with a `\` plus the original character

so giving thats string and array

```
string origin = "words&sales -test\strange";
string[] specialChars = new string[]{"\", "&", "-", "?",......};
```

i want to get

```
"words\&sales \-test\\strange"
```

notice that the `\` itself is a character to find and replace

thanks

Comment: When you say "efficient" - do you have a performance objective in mind?

Comment: yes, i don't known exactly best way to avoid performance issue and keep memory allocation low. now i'am thinking about looping with a search to find char position and add the slash in that positions

Comment: @gt.guybrush "to find char position and add the slash in that positions" <-- That won't work: `string` values are immutable, so you cannot simply insert characters into a string - and even if `string` values were mutable like a `char[]`, they're all still a _contiguous_ sequence of `char` values: they are not a linked-list, so you simply can't insert... at least not without an expensive reallocation and copying.

Comment: @Dai, right, i omiss adding it while creating new string, but it seems not good anyway

Comment: `string rep = Regex.Replace(@"words&sales -test\strange", @"\\|&|\-|\?", @"\$0");`

Comment: @Jimi can you argue it more? can be used to replace string too and not only char? thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That replaces the symbols you specify with `"\"` + the symbol itself and generates a new string with the result. To know whether it performs better or worse than a StringBuilder (hard), test it in a .Net Fx 4.8 app and a .Net 6+ app (and many strings of very different sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the fastest way to build `String` values in C#/.NET is with a `StringBuilder`, even if you're transforming another `String` value.

The other problem is the "best" way to determine which char values should be escaped or not: if the set of escapable characters is fixed at compile-time, then use a `switch()` statement, as that will be compiled to a native jump-table, which is faster than using a runtime `HashSet<Char>` for determining set-membership:

e.g.:

```cs
static String Escape( String input )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: 5 * input.Length / 4 ); // Assuming 25% length increase due to escaping.

    foreach( Char c in input )
    {
        switch( c )
        {
        case '\\':
        case '&':
        case '-':
        case '?':
            _ = sb.Append( '\\' ).Append( c );
            break;
        default:
            _ = sb.Append( c );
            break;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

If the set of escapable character is defined at runtime then using a `HashSet<Char>` will likely be the best overall option - though if you know you're only processing chars with Unicode code-points within a limited range (say ASCII-compatible chars in the range `0x00 to 0x7F`) then you could use a `Boolean[127]` array to store the escape flag map.

Using a `HashSet<Char>`, it would be like this:

```cs
static String Escape( String input, IEnumerable<Char> escapableChars )
{
    HashSet<Char> escapeThese = new HashSet<Char>( escapableChars );

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( capacity: 5 * input.Length / 4 ); // Assuming 25% length increase due to escaping.

    foreach( Char c in input )
    {
        if( escapeThese.Contains( c ) )
        {
            _ = sb.Append( '\\' ).Append( c );
        }
        else
        {
            _ = sb.Append( c );
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Of course, the above code can be optimized further: some suggestions:

- First check to see if the `String input` even has any escapable characters in the first place: if none of its characters are escapable then just return `input` directly without having created a new `StringBuilder`.
- Create an (on-demand) pool of `StringBuilder` instances instead of creating new instances on every call.
- Allow `ReadOnlySpan<Char>` instead of `String` for input and writing output to `Span<Char>` - you'll need an initial step to calculate the required minimum size of the `Span<Char>` first though, and pass that info back to the caller.

  - The same minimum-size calculation can be done to have an exactly correct `capacity:` value for the `StringBuilder` instead of my (lazy) 25% estimate.
- Add memoization: use a Bloom filter and output cache keyed by the `input` value.

Comment: setting stringbuilder capacity is for performance correct? i'm even wondering if that solution can be used eve to simply remove special characters

Comment: @gt.guybrush Yes , though the performance benefits of preallocating a `StringBuilder`'s `capacity` are not much to write home about - especially for shorter strings (under a few hundred chars).

Comment: The dynamics of the values you're processing are important too.  Lots of tiny strings might not warrent a string builder at all, where as larger string could benefit quiet a bit.  Likewise, if lots of the inputs have no special chars, a presense check before you start writing strings could be beneficial.

Comment: ok, origin strings will be tiny and strange char will appears few time. not mandatory but i can have double chars to remove: ? it's ok, while ?? should become \??

Comment: @Ian Escaping a string still requires scanning through it and rebuilding it - the only "tiny" strings where you could get-away with char-by-char `String` concatenation would be under ~5 chars in length, I reckon...

Comment: @Dai I agree, which is why I asked about the context before providing an answer.  They've been described as "tiny", which remains a bit vague, but could reach this scope.  The bigger win is probably the checking step - if most inputs have no special chars, you can save a lot of allocations by doing a read-only test first.